# VB6 control listview - ordenamiento

Tags: vb6

En mi trabajo me toca retocar una utilidad de muchos años programada en vb6 ... todo muy bien, excepto que me había olvidado del control listview , que solo ordena por strings. He buscado y probado cantidad de funciones ... no pude dar con una que funcione , o no lo he logrado.
Los datos son registros resultantes de una consulta PL SQL a una base Oracle .. la cual ya recibo ordenada por el ORDER BY.
Al cargar los datos a mi Listview (Lvdatos) , he probado de convertir a string y agregarle 0 a la izquierda ...
La idea es que estoy reporteando un ranking y que el numero mayor quede arriba y el ordenamiento Descendente.
Parte del código que carga el Listview :

```
        For b1 = 1 To a1
            DoEvents
            lblCount.Caption = b1
            PB1.value = b1
            Carga_Datos (Trim(RsListado!SLOT))

            Set subelemento = LvDatos.ListItems.Add(, CStr(b1) & "M", CStr(b1))
            subelemento.SubItems(1) = CStr(RsListado!SLOT)
            subelemento.SubItems(2) = dato_area
            subelemento.SubItems(3) = dato_isla
            subelemento.SubItems(4) = dato_juego

            If Trim(RsListado!MOTIVO) > 0 Then
                subelemento.SubItems(5) = Trae_Motivo(RsListado!MOTIVO)
                Else
                subelemento.SubItems(5) = "No ingresado"
            End If


            canti_cad = CStr(RsListado!CANTIDAD)

            If Len(canti_cad) = 2 Then canti_cad = "0" & canti_cad
            If Len(canti_cad) = 1 Then canti_cad = "00" & canti_cad


            subelemento.SubItems(6) = canti_cad
```

Esto no me funcionó , alguien podría tirarme alguna idea ? Gracias !

Comment: el listview no era el que se usa en el navegador?? no tenia varias formas de ordenamiento segun las columnas que tiene?

Comment: Si es el ListView común de Microsoft, tienes las propiedades `SortKey` para indicar la columna y `SortOrder` si quieres ascendente o descendente. Hasta dónde lo probé, es inteligente como para saber si el dato es numérico y ordenar en consecuencia.

Comment: a que te refieres con "no funcionó"?

Comment: Hola , finalmente no me hizo falta ordenar numéricamente, por ello lo dejé como estaba. Estuve viendo las posibilidades y , en efecto, el listview de vb6 solo ordena alfabéticamente . Con numéricos no funciona correctamente ninguna de las propiedades de ordenamiento, a menos que se eche mano a clasificar o se realicen procesos para convertir y desconvertir, pero no me hizo falta. Gracias x la ayuda.

Comment: finalmente no me hizo falta ordenar numéricamente, por ello lo dejé como estaba. Estuve viendo las posibilidades y , en efecto, el listview de vb6 solo ordena alfabéticamente . Con numéricos no funciona correctamente ninguna de las propiedades de ordenamiento, a menos que se eche mano a clasificar o se realicen procesos para convertir y desconvertir, pero no me hizo falta. Gracias x la ayuda.